# What permission controls the Iterations checkbox in TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs

I would like to grant a user the ability to check and uncheck iteration checkboxes for a specific iteration path in a TFS 2013 Team Project. This person is a scrum master and would like to be able to manage the iterations that appear in the Team backlog.

[image: Iteration checkboxes]

I have granted the following iteration level permissions but the checkboxes are still read-only for the user.

[image: Iteration permissions]

The only way I have found to grant edit rights to these checkboxes is by adding the user to the Project Administrators group which I would rather not do. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see on the [authorization matrix on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523998.aspx), the [Schedule Sprints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523998.aspx) activity is possible through the Team Administrator.

[image]

[This blog post explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishp/archive/2014/02/07/how-to-grant-project-manager-s-privileges-in-tfs-but-without-outright-granting-project-administrator-privileges.aspx) some more advanced TFS admin tricks to further limit and control similar permissions.